# How can I run a PHP file on my mac remotely?

Tags: php, macos

I have a PHP file that communicates with iOS devices via [APNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service). I would like to be able to access (and run) this file remotely from anywhere in the world.

I know that I can do that with a real server, but my questions are:

1. Can I get a universal IP so that I can run this file on my mac remotely using a browser?
2. Are there any tools/simple services to do this for development purposes, so that I can simply put my files in there and get some URL to fire it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks, that sounds nice, but i couldn't find a guide to do that. i will look more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It runs on your machine(Mac in this case), and lets you access it via a subdomain of ngrok.com, such as curneliousmac.ngrok.com.

It's free and doesn't require any sort of port forwarding or firewall enabling, it should just work.

Comment: thanks a lot, i actually have tried that ,and its not working.. you open the file, than the terminal is opened, and you just cant type anything in there. there is something said about a process completed, and you cant do anything.

Comment: You have to open a terminal and run the file, passing in some arguments to tell it what you want to do.

For example, if you downloaded the file to /home/Curnelious/Downloads, you'd open your terminal window and do "cd /home/Curnelious/Downloads; ngrok 80"

Answer (score 3):

[Configure your router](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=router+port+forwarding) to forward external requests to [TCP port 80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_80) on to your Mac (which is presumably running Apache). This will allow anyone who knows your [public IP address](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=What+is+my+IP) to connect to your Mac by typing `http://123.123.123.123` into the URL bar of their browser.

You'll probably want to consider using a dynamic DNS service (such as [Duck DNS](http://duckdns.org/about.jsp)) so that users don't have to type the raw IP address in. This is also useful if you have a dynamic IP address, as you'd simply need to update the IP stored by the dynamic DNS service rather than telling everyone who needed access what the *new* IP was.